# React how to handle error response from Nodejs/Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, post, error-handling

I'm performing a validation check on a Domain name entered by a user (eg.`google.com`) in my Nodejs back-end which will return either a good `200` response or bad `404` response if the domain entered was invalid.

In my React front-end I have the following code which sends the `POST` request:

```
const response = await
    fetch('/new-cert', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },

        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({domainInput: domainInputValue})
    });

// Show error message if domain is invalid
if (!response.ok) {
    this.setState({
        validDomain: false
    });
} else {
    this.setState({
        domainAdded: domainInputValue,
        domainInputValue: '', // Clear input text
        validDomain: true
    });
}
```

However, my app is getting blocked and running really slow when it gets a `404` response, how do I correctly handle this error so that my app continues to run normally after I call `setState`?
I've tried some try-catch blocks but couldn't get them working.

Comment: add your try-catch code.

Comment: I just put it around the `const response` block with nothing in the catch, didn't really know what I was doing, please write an answer if you know how to write it properly :)

Comment: What do you mean by your app is blocked? Should any state be set when 404 is returned?

Comment: Like it becomes really slow and doesn't let me add more domains and make more `POST` requests. I don't know if I used the correct error code, but basically I just wanted to return an error code from Nodejs to React informing it that the domain the user entered was invalid and to display an error message to them

Comment: Sounds like there's some other problems. Can you replicate it on https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: Sorry it does let me make more POST requests successfully but the app just becomes really slow